# how to count the total comment

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the total comment/post posted on my page. i have a table in my database named test. within table i have a column named comment, where every post is been stored. the problem am having is to echo out the total number of comment and keep updating as viewers keep on posting there comment and i tried using this code

```
<?php
 $handle = mysql_query("SELECT `comment`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
 FROM test GROUP BY `comment` ");

if ($handle) {
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle);
echo ($results[0]['count'] + $results[1]['count']);
}
?>
```

but it keep on echoing out 0. pls help me out.

Comment: If you only count(*) and dont display Comment, then you dont need to group by.

Comment: where is mysql_connect in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list($count) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select count(*) from `test`"));
echo $count;
```

Alternatively, if you are already running a query to get some comments, you can try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select sql_calc_found_rows * from `test` order by `id` desc limit 10");
// ^ Get the 10 most recent comments
list($count) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select found_rows()"));
// this avoids having to run the entire query again, great for efficiency!
while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) var_dump($comment); // just an example
```

Comment: tanx allot am grateful @ Niet the Dark Absol, i used your post and it work like magic.